# Linux kernel modules - redundant includes

Tags: c, linux, kernel

There are some tutorials out there that `#include` the following headers

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
```

However, the module works just fine without them; mere `linux/module.h` included. **Are the two includes necessary?**

Comment: Often there are dependencies between header files, so `module.h` includes the other header files. But you shouldn't depend on it, and include all the required headers.

Comment: If it compiles without them, then they weren't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

As [stark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1216776/stark) said, they are probably unnecessary in some specific cases. If you find it on some tutorials, it was probably because the writer simply copy/paste-d his headers to gain some time.

Looking at `module.h`:

> ```
> #include <linux/init.h>
> #include <linux/kobject.h>
> ```

and `kobject.h`:

> ```
> #include <linux/kernel.h>
> ```

However, unused #include should be removed because they may have some negative effects like increasing compilation time and memory usage.

A tool called [Include what you use](https://include-what-you-use.org) can help people to track unused #includes.